# Extract href from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I used

```
var hyper=document.querySelectorAll("a")
 for (var i=0; i<hyper.length; i++)
 {
     hyper[i].onmouseover=function()
     {
            alert("hyperlink");
     }
 }
```

to alert on a hyperlink via a greasemonkey script. Now, I want to get the `href` of `hyper[i]` so that I can handle different url's.

I tried `hyper[i].href`, but it's not working. What's the code to do this?

Comment: `this.href`. Basic JavaScript you'd learn in a DOM programming tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.href`, since you're in an event handler the `this` context refers to the element being moused over.